# Track Sessions with Product Views

Tags: commerce, google-analytics

Commerce Google Tag Manager module provides following rule actions:

1. Send "Add to Cart" event to google analytics via GTM
2. Send "Remove from Cart" event to google analytics via GTM
3. Send "Checkout" event to google analytics via GTM
4. Send "Purchase" event to google analytics via GTM

Created following 4 rules:

1. Send Add to Cart Details to GA via GTM
   Event: After adding a product to the cart
   Action: Send "Add to Cart" event to google analytics via GTM
2. Send Remove From Cart to GA via GTM (Not having any session in GTM to track these details)
   Event: After removing a product from the cart
   Action: Send "Remove from Cart" event to google analytics via GTM
3. Send Checkout Complete Details to GA via GTM
   Event: Completing the checkout process
   Action: Send "Purchase" event to google analytics via GTM
4. Send Checkout Process Details to GA via GTM
   Event: Process a change to the checkout page (Enabled Commerce Rules Extra module for this event)
   Action: Send "Checkout" event to google analytics via GTM

Using above 4 rules data is tracking properly under Ecommerce -> Shopping Analysis->Shopping Behavior Analysis to 'All Sessions', 'Sessions with Add to Cart', 'Sessions with Check-Out', 'Sessions with Transactions' but 'Sessions with Product Views' is empty. Please help.

How to track Sessions with Product Views data to Google Analytics via GTM in drupal 7?